# I can not rotate a vector using rotate_vector_by_quaternion of tfquaternion

Tags: python, tensorflow, rotation, quaternions

I want to rotate a vector by quaternion using `tfquaternion`. but I am getting the following error

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'normalized'`.

```py
import tfquaternion as tfq
train_points = tfq.rotate_vector_by_quaternion(transf[:,3:],train_points)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `tfq.rotate_vector_by_quaternion` is expecting `transf[:,3:]` to be a `tfq.Quaternion`, but it's just an `np.ndarray`, causing your error. You could try converting it first:

```
import tfquaternion as tfq
train_points = tfq.rotate_vector_by_quaternion(tfq.Quaternion(transf[:,3:]), train_points)
```

Does that work?